# Where can I find the source code of ftpd?

Tags: debian, networking, ftp, source

How can I inspect  *`ftpd`*(the regular Linux FTP server's) source code on my machine?

I'm using Debian 9. Unfortunately I can't figure out which exactly implementation has the package ftpd which I previously installed through `apt install ftpd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you’re using Debian, if your repositories are set up correctly (and they are by default),

```
apt-get source ftpd
```

will download and extract the source code for your `ftpd` package in a sub-directory of the current directory — on Debian 9, that will be `ftpd-0.17-36`.

This works for any package downloaded from the Debian repositories, as long as the corresponding `deb-src` entries are present in your repository configuration.